# How to Cover apexpages.currentpage().geturl()

Tags: unit-test, failing-tests

In my constructor I'm declaring as

```
pagenm = ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl().substringbetween('apex/','?');
```

And in the action button I'm writing these lines

```
if(pagenm = 'Page1'){
   // some code here
}else if(pagenm = 'Page2'){
  // some code here
}
```

Now I need to cover these lines in Apex class.I'm getting

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

at pagenm in constructor. How should I put the url in test class.

Comment: Can you provide source of your test method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Test Class you need to set the current page and put the parameters that you want in the url.

**For e.g.**

```
Test.startTest();
   PageReference myVfPage = Page.YOUR_VF_PAGE;
   myVfPage.getParameters().put('id',SOME_ID);
   myVfPage.getParameters().put('param2','TestContact123');
   Test.setCurrentPage(myVfPage); 

   String id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
Test.stopTest();
```

In above case add the parameter that you require in your code to successfully execute the business logic